# How to match Golang regex over multiple lines when there is new line character?

Tags: regex, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
        r, _ := regexp.Compile(`OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)`)
        str := "OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:A-a-**\n**9-!OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:B-b-8-"
        fmt.Printf("%q\n", r.FindString(str))
}
```

I am trying to match a pattern. Note `\n` in the `str` variable.
I am not able to match the pattern `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)` because of `\n` in `str` variable.

The string which I expect to match is `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:A-a-9-`, but I get a match for `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:A-a-` since `9-` is after `\n`

Comment: Add `\n` to the character class, `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:([a-zA-Z0-9\n-]+)`. Or, remove all `\n`  before running your regex (this might be simpler if you need a value without a newline, see [demo](https://play.golang.org/p/KwirT5nA_0x)).

Answer (score 9):

Try multi-line mode:

- https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/ - turn on my `m` flag

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
        r, _ := regexp.Compile("(?m)OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:([a-zA-Z0-9*-]+)")
        str := "OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:A-a-**\n**9-!OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:B-b-8-"
        fmt.Printf("%q\n", r.FindString(str))
}
```

Output:

```
"OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:A-a-**"
```

- or allow `\n` matching as any character - turn on with `s` flag

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
        r, _ := regexp.Compile("(?s)OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:([a-zA-Z0-9*\n-]+)")
        str := "OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:A-a-**\n**9-!OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:B-b-8-"
        fmt.Printf("%q\n", r.FindString(str))
}
```

Output:

```
"OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:A-a-**\n**9-"
```

(Also I've added `*` as allowed character)